# Does mimamsa accept gita?

Tags: bhagavad-gita, purva-mimamsa

Does the mimamsa school of thought in Hinduism accept Gita as a good source of information and knowledge?

Comment: They don't. That's why Gita 2.45-46 and several Upanishads bash them saying they are deviating from proper path. I mean Mimasarkas don't accept Vedanta hence Gita bashes them.